# phpMyAdmin - mySQL - Error importing data into wordpress - what is collation?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am having problems importing data what does collation mean?

The reason I ask is I keep getting an error importing data.. So I am looking at my wp-config file and the collation reads as follows.

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

So I go over to phpMyAdmin and the Server charset is UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) I don't know if this has any meaning but in the server connection collation box it reads `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Here's where I think the problem lies but I am a total newbie with mySQL. My main wordpress database has collation type `latin1_swedish_ci` next to it - under collation.

When I click into the database they all have utf8 charsets different ones some `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and some `utf8_general_ci` - does this mean the database is set up incorrectly?

Could this be the cause of my import problems and how do I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

here some from wiki :

```
Collation is the assembly of written information into a standard order. 
Many systems of collation are based on numerical order or alphabetical 
order, or extensions and combinations thereof.
```

my opinion, it is the character set for the database...
and if you want to import your database to another place, the collation must be the same / both servers having the same collation,,,

Answer (score 0):

the collation can be change befor export so I wont give you this error .I had the previous pb and this worked for me .1)I change the collation to the same as the sever 2)I chose option when exporting to utf8 .

You cant change the collation in notepad .You have to make sure of this steps in phpmyadmin